# how to use "in" to delete multiple records (by using parameter)

Tags: mysql, vb.net, sqlite

I'm trying to delete multiple records in one statement
I use the following Sql:

```
DELETE FROM `tblregs2` WHERE `RegdID` IN (@RegdID)
```

and I collect the parameter value during execute the codes and save the values inside a string variable.

but the result that I get is: "1,2,3,4"
so the SQL statement will be:

```
DELETE FROM `tblregs2` WHERE `RegdID` IN ("1,2,3,4")
```

but "in" doesn't accept the double quotation so I need to use it like 1,2,3,4

```
    DELETE FROM `tblregs2` WHERE `RegdID` IN (1,2,3,4)
```

how to get a result like that?

by the way, the code is working with "FIND_IN_SET" but I'm working with two database types (MySQL + SQLite) so "In" works with both of them.

Comment: Do you want code that works in both databases?

Comment: query parameters are not substituted directly into the command text. They are always kept separate, _even on the database_ in order to keep you safe from sql injection issues. _There is no resulting new SQL statement._ Therefore the fix here needs to go a level deeper, to where the RegId values is constructed.

Comment: @forpas yes, I tried but I didn't got good result

Comment: There is no way that I can think of for the same code to run in both MySql and SQLite, unless PIPES_AS_CONCAT SQL mode is enabled in MySql in which case the operator `||` can be used as the concatenation operator.

Comment: If you want to pass 4 values to a mysql statement, then you need 4 parameters, not just one.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I can't believe I am saying this but don't use parameters. If you are parsing each number for you string you should avoid Sql injection.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim s = "1,2,3,4"
    Dim strSQL = $"DELETE FROM `tblregs2` WHERE `RegdID` IN ({s})"
    MessageBox.Show(strSQL)
End Sub
```